# MySQL select with OR operator

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlcommand

In C# desktop application I use `MySqlConnection` `MySqlCommand` `cmd.CommandText`:

```
"select * from reg where username='" + user + "' and password='" + pass + "' and key='" + key + "'";
```

to selects records, but I'm trying to figure out, how to use `OR` operator with condition, if I want check both `user` `OR` `email` from single input like `string UserOrEmail = textBox1.Text.Trim();`.

Looks like condition  works for `username=` or `email=`, but in this case following values checking does not works, seems like I have to use some correct way here:

```
"select * from reg where username='" + UserOrEmail + "' or email='" + UserOrEmail + "' and password='" + pass + "' and key='" + key + "'";
```

Comment: first of all: ***use parameterised queries*** - otherwise you're wide open for SQL injection attacks and prone to numerous syntax errors in the future. second: ***never ever ever ever*** store passwords as plain text - ***hash them***. (and no: "i'm still learning" is not a valid excuse - learn it _the right way_ from the start)

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need parentheses because the operator `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`:

```
"select * from reg where (username='" + UserOrEmail + "' or email='" + UserOrEmail + "') and password='" + pass + "' and key='" + key + "'";
```

Or use the operator `IN`:

```
"select * from reg where '" + UserOrEmail + "' in (username, email) and password='" + pass + "' and key='" + key + "'";
```